# php mysql login/register current logged in user different code

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am making a site with a register and login via php and mysql.
Now i can't get something working and need help with.
I want to show if a user is logged in and it shows the username.
In below code i already have a session but i can't shows who is logged in or anything.

```html
    <html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../opmaak/music.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="streep">
   <a href="home.php"><img src="home.png"></a>
   <a href="music.html"><img src="music.png"></a>
   <a href="form.php" style="float:right"><img src="mail.png"></a>
   <a href="foto.html" style="float:right"><img src="foto.png"></a>
   <a href="social.html"><img src="social.png"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box">
   <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <label>Gebruikersnaam:</label><input type="text" name="user"><br/>
    <label>Wachtwoord:</label><input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"><br/>
    <!--New user Register Link -->
    <p><a href="register.php">Nieuwe gebruiker</a></p>
    </form>
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
      if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
      //DB Connection
      $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysqli_error());
      //Select DB From database
      $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'test') or die("databse error");
      //Selecting database
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM userpass WHERE user='".$user."' AND pass='".$pass."'");
      $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if($numrows !=0)
     {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
     {
      $dbusername=$row['user'];
      $dbpassword=$row['pass'];
     }
      if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
     {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;
      //Redirect Browser
      header("Location:home.php");
     }
     }
      else
     {
      echo "Foute gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord";
     }
     }
      else
     {
      echo "Required All fields!";
     }
     }
     
    ?>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bobby Tables is gonna getya, which is doubly bad given that you seem to be storing passwords in plaintext.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `session_start()` at the start of the PhP document otherwise it will not work.

Putting

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

at the start should do the trick.

Comment: Can you use " instead of ' in $_SESSION[""]

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine. Make sure to use the same function `session_start()` in the file home.php .
Am also assuming you have no errors in your sql queries.

Comment: i have and indeed i have no errors of any kind but it won't show me the username i logged in with any were

Comment: If its redirecting to home.php, can we see how you are calling it? And hopefully the value from the database is not an empty string.

Comment: well now i fixed it it now shows that i am signed in but if i sign out i get this error: Notice: Undefined index: sess_user in C:\Users\jordi\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\site\htmlenphp\home.php on line 69

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but you have to check if the session is set before you echo it.